# how to calculate the median with linprog?

Tags: python

I tried to calculate the median using scipy's linprog command in two examples:
first on a list, I found the same results, and here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
 from scipy.optimize import linprog
```

**First Example:**

```
n=9
y = np. array([100,90,67,0,29,0,11,4,20])
y=y[:,np.newaxis]
#first method
my=np.median(y)
print(my)
sy = sorted(y)
print(sy)
print(sy[2])
```

the result was:20

**second method:**

```
 X=np.ones(n, dtype = int)
    X=X[:,np.newaxis]
I=np.eye(n,n)
tau=0.5
A= np.c_[X,-X,I,-I]
b = y
c1=np.zeros(2, dtype = int)
c1=c1[np.newaxis,:]
c2=np.ones(n, dtype = int)
c2=c2[np.newaxis,:]
c3=np.ones(n, dtype = int)
c3=c3[np.newaxis,:]
c= np.c_[c1,tau*c2,(1-tau)*c3]
res = linprog(c, A_eq=A, b_eq=b,bounds=None)
print('Optimal value:', res.fun, '\nX:', res.x)
print(res.x[16])
```

the result was:20
the second example,I generated numbers according to a lognormal law. I found different results, the code is:

**first method:**

```
np.random.seed(1)
std=1
y=lognorm.rvs(std, size=9)
y=y[:, np.newaxis]
my=np.median(y)
print(my)
```

the result was 0.5896820696846964

**second method:**

```
X=np.ones(n, dtype = int)
X=X[:,np.newaxis]
I=np.eye(n,n)
tau=0.5
A= np.c_[X,-X,I,-I]
b = y
c1=np.zeros(2, dtype = int)
c1=c1[np.newaxis,:]
c2=np.ones(n, dtype = int)
c2=c2[np.newaxis,:]
c3=np.ones(n, dtype = int)
c3=c3[np.newaxis,:]
c= np.c_[c1,tau*c2,(1-tau)*c3]
res = linprog(c, A_eq=A, b_eq=b,bounds=None)
print('Optimal value:', res.fun, '\nX:', res.x)
print(res.x)
```

but in this method, I don't find the result in res.x

Comment: THANKS, A LOT OF FRIENDS.